# The problem of repeated display of an element in the view

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core

I have a problem in displaying the product gallery. Thank you for your help.
At the time of displaying the product, the image gallery will automatically repeat itself twice
code:

```
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="sp-loading" style="display: none;">
                    <img id="img-gallery" src="/ProductFile/Images/@Model.ProductImoageName" alt=""><br>loadingpicture
                </div>
                <div class="sp-wrap sp-non-touch" style="display:inline-block;">
                    <div class="sp-large">
                        @foreach (var item in galleries)
                        {
                        <a href="/ProductFile/Gallery/@item.ImageName" class="sp-current-big">
                            <img id="img-gallery" src="/ProductFile/Gallery/@item.ImageName">
                        </a>
                        }
                    </div>

                    <div class="sp-thumbs sp-tb-active">
                    @foreach (var item in galleries)
                    {
                        <a href="/ProductFile/Gallery/@item.ImageName" style="background-image:url('/ProductFile/Gallery/@item.ImageName'); background-repeat:no-repeat; ">
                            
                        </a>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
   </div>
            </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpfl4.png)

no-repeat It was not used
I want to have an image gallery

Comment: This part of your `sp-loading` class is not shown by default, so it is not in the picture you provided, right? Is the `sp-large` class the big picture part? You load the images in the foreach and it should load all three images. The code you provided does not reproduce your problem, including the corresponding structure in the picture.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://vishartech.com/ShowProduct/2

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, what you provided is the page you loaded and I can't find the problem. I tried to build the page and load it, but it only loads once, not in your case, maybe you used a library or CSS style that caused this problem. Can you provide an example of a reproducible problem?